# Let $V$ consist of all real inf. sequences $\{x_n\}$ for which $\sum x_n^2$ converges. Prove $V$ is a v. sp. with inner product $(x,y)=\sum x_n y_n$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

this problem is from Apostol Volume 2. I would like to be sure my work is correct.

The problem:

> Let $V$ consist of all real infinite sequences $\{x_n\}$ for which the series $\sum x_n^2$ converges. Prove $V$ is a vector space with inner product $(x,y) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n y_n$, where $x = \{x_n\} \in V, y = \{y_n\} \in V$.

First of all, recall that the set of all infinite sequences form a vector space. It therefore follows that we only need to show that $V$ forms a subspace of this space. Let $\{x_n\},\{y_n\} \in V$. Then $\sum (x_n + y_n)^2 = \sum x_n^2 + \sum y_n^2 + \sum 2x_n y_n$. It is clear that the first two sums converge by definition of $V$. Notice that $$\left( \sum_{n=1}^M x_n y_n \right) \le \left( \sum_{n=1}^M x_n^2 \right) \left( \sum_{n=1}^M y_n^2 \right)$$ by Cauchy-Schwarz. It follows that $\sum x_n^2 + \sum y_n^2 + \sum 2x_n y_n \le \sum x_n^2 + \sum y_n^2 + 2 \left(\sum x_n^2\right)\left(\sum y_n^2\right)$, and since every sum on the right converges, we can conclude that $\sum (x_n + y_n)^2$ converges. Therefore, $\{x_n + y_n\} \in V$.

Next, set $\{x_n\} = \{0\}$ and therefore $0 \in V$. Finally, let $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and note that $\sum (ax_n)^2 = \sum a^2 x_n^2 = a^2 \sum x_n^2$, which converges. Therefore, $\{ax_n\} \in V$.

We will now show that $(x,y) = \sum x_n y_n$ is an inner product of $V$. Clearly $(x,y) = (y,x)$, $(x,y + z) = (x,y) + (x,z)$ and $(ax,y) = a(x,y)$. Note that $(x,x) = \sum x_n^2$ converges, and by the trivial inequality, each term is $\ge 0$, and since $\sum x_n^2 = 0$, it follows that each individual term must be $0$ as well.

Comment: It seems to be correct.

Comment: @GreyFox Thanks, any additional feedback?

Comment: @polite_proofs Just one about vector subspaces. When you prove that $V$ is closed under scalar multiplication then automatically $0\in V$. Checking this condition is more interesting when you are trying to prove that the set is not a subspace.